# Sum values in foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach, count

```
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key. " = " .$value. "<br>";
}
```

For example:

> doc1 = 8
>
> doc2 = 7
>
> doc3 = 1

I want to count $value, so the result is 8+7+1 = 16. What should i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Just initialize a variable to 0 outside the loop, and add each `$value` to it inside the loop. Seriously, this is a really elementary general beginner programming question; make sure you're clear on the real basic concepts before you try to go farther, since otherwise you're going to encounter a lot of things that won't make sense to you.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 23):

In your case IF you want to go with foreach loop than

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key => $value) {
   $sum += $value; 
}
echo $sum;
```

But if you want to go with direct sum of array than look on below for your solution :

```
$total = array_sum($group);
```

for **only sum of array** looping is time wasting.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

array_sum — Calculate the sum of values in an array

```
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";

$b = array("a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.3, "c" => 3.4);
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($b) . "\n";
?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
sum(a) = 20
sum(b) = 6.9
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use **[`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)**.

```
$total = array_sum($group);
```

Comment: I can imagine someone hasn't upvoted this. Everyone seems to be reinventing the wheel

Comment: To be fair, the algorithm is so trivial sometimes people forget that things like this exist in the standard library. Sometimes SO gets locked into a mob mentality, up voting answers while ignoring others because the first one _works_.

Answer (score 5):

Use `+=`

```
$val = 0;

foreach($arr as $var) {
   $val += $var; 
}

echo $val;
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer if not using "as value" in your foreach!

Answer (score 0):

```
$total=0;
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
   echo $key. " = " .$value. "<br>"; 
   $total+= $value;
}
echo $total;
```