# Counting values in a conditional statement withing a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following foreach loop:

```
foreach($socialNetworks as $socialNetworksKey){    
    if($userUrl == NULL){
      echo $snName . ' is empty.' .  '<br/>';
     $value = 1;
    }
   elseif (strpos($userUrl,$snUrl) === false) { 
     echo $snName . '</b> address must start with <b>' . $snUrl  .  '</b><br/>';}
   else {
    echo 'Values are correct' .  '<br/>';
    $value = 1;
   }
 echo 'Value equals ' . count($value) .  '<br/>';
 }
```

The foreach loop source is an array. The foreach loop works correctly as desired.

Though I wish that I get the count/sum of the value of  $value. For example if the 'if' and 'else' statements for the arrays are correct and I have 4 arrays this would count to 4. If 3 out of 4 arrays are correct the sum would be 3.

I tried using this and it worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535630/sum-values-in-foreach-loop-php) but when I echo it is displaying all the numbers from one and doing a summation all the time, but I want only to count $value and display the final value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the echo outside of the `foreach` loop. I would do the following:

```
$value = 0;
foreach($socialNetworks as $socialNetworksKey){    
    if($userUrl == NULL){
      echo $snName . ' is empty.' .  '<br/>';
      $value++;
    }
   elseif (strpos($userUrl,$snUrl) === false) { 
      echo $snName . '</b> address must start with <b>' . $snUrl  .  '</b><br/>';}
   else {
      echo 'Values are correct' .  '<br/>';
      $value++;
   }
 }
 echo 'Value equals ' . $value .  '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
$value += 1;
```

which is the same as

```
$value = $value + 1;
```

instead of

```
$value = 1;
```

and you should put this line outside of foreach loop

```
echo 'Value equals ' . count($value) .  '<br/>';
```

So you should have this.

```
foreach($socialNetworks as $socialNetworksKey){    
    if($userUrl == NULL){
        echo $snName . ' is empty.' .  '<br/>';
        $value += 1;
    }elseif (strpos($userUrl,$snUrl) === false) { 
        echo $snName . '</b> address must start with <b>' . $snUrl  .  '</b><br/>';}
    else {
        echo 'Values are correct' .  '<br/>';
        $value += 1;
    }
}
echo 'Value equals ' . count($value) .  '<br/>';
```