# how to count all results of foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql

Let say we have following database table `items`

```
-----------------------------
ID |  ITEM  | PRICE | SALES |
-----------------------------
1  | item1  | 5.00  | 1     |
2  | item2  | 4.00  | 5     |
3  | item3  | 2.00  | 2     |
-----------------------------
```

This means `item1` price was `5.00` and sold `1` times

how then we calculate total earning ! meaning for each item we will multpli its price with number of sale to get total earning for this item

```
$earning_per_item1 = $a1['PRICE']*$a1['SALES']; // for item1 = 5*1
```

But what if i want to get the total earning for all items?

This should be `29`

Comment: is this a php or an sql question?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535630/sum-values-in-foreach-loop-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535630/sum-values-in-foreach-loop-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT sum(i.PRICE * i.SALES)
FROM items i;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c51/2/0)