# Get one total sum for repeated rows in @foreach Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've found [Sum values in foreach loop php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535630/sum-values-in-foreach-loop-php)
but I need to adapt it to my case. I have table with three ratings and `user_id`. I need to get average from all of ratings of each user in admin table. If for example user made two works and having 5,5,5 and 5,5,4 I want to display 4.835 , but instead of this I get:

user_id -- average

200 -- 4.67 | 4.835 |

I need:

200 -- 4.835

Controller:

```
$feedbacks = DB::table('feedback')->groupBy('user_id')->paginate(100);
$feedbacks_get = DB::table('feedback')->get();
```

Blade:

```
@foreach( $feedbacks as $wrk)
        <tr>
        <td>
        {{$wrk->user_id}}
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php $sum = 0;$i = 0;?>
        @foreach($feedbacks_get as $e)
        @if ( $e->user_id == $wrk->user_id)
        <?php
        $i++;
        $sum+= (($e->rating1 + $e->rating2 + $e->rating3 ))/3;
        $result= round($sum,2)/$i   .' | ';
        if($result<=4){
          echo '<span class="red;">'.$result.'</span>' ;
        }
        elseif($result>4){
          echo $result;
        }
        ?>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        </td>
        </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        @foreach( $feedbacks as $wrk)
    <tr>
    <td>
    {{$wrk->user_id}}
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php $sum = 0;$i = 0;?>
    @foreach($feedbacks_get as $e)
    @if ( $e->user_id == $wrk->user_id)
    <?php
    $i++;
    $sum+= (($e->rating1 + $e->rating2 + $e->rating3 ))/3;

    ?>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    $result= round($sum,2)/$i   ;
    if($result<=4){
      echo '<span class="red;">'.$result.'|</span>' ;
    }
    elseif($result>4){
      echo $result.' | ';
    }
    </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Wow! Works... Now I trying to understand how it works :) Actually I knew that biggest value is what I need.. Seems that change should show only biggest value.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a database query in Laravel is always a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections), so you can use these functions to do this automatically like so:

```
$average = $feedbacks_get->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->map(function ($feedback) {
        return ($feedback->rating1 + $feedback->rating2 + $feedback->rating3) / 3;
    })
    ->avg();
```

Comment: If I provide exact value ->where('user_id', 200)->... I get "Call to a member function where() on array".  Same thing happens if try to add your code to foreach. Sorry but I didn't understood how to output table of all workers with all theirs averages.