# How to add the values from a foreach loop php

Tags: php

I have and foreach loop that outputs the totals I want to add when i echo the $val_tex it outputs in one number like "4911165" but if I echo it with a break tag it gives me the right values. It looks like

49

1

1

1

65

My question is how to get the sum of all the values which should equal "117"

```
$val_tex = array();

foreach ( $get_seller as $keys ) {

     $val_tex = $keys['total']; 

}
```

Comment: `echo array_sum(array_column($get_seller, 'total'));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum values in foreach loop php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535630/sum-values-in-foreach-loop-php)

Comment: I like how this person didn't interact with anyone or even bother to respond about if anything is now working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add them together in the foreach loop - there's a simple way to do that $total += $keys['total']; It's just a simpler way of saying $total = $total + $keys['total'];

There are also other ways - `$total = array_sum(array(1,2,3,4)); // == 10` for example. To get the sum from a single column, you get an array that only contains the values from the specific column first:

```
// an array of the values from that column
$arrayTotall = array_column($keys, 'total'); 
$total = array_sum($arrayTotals);
```

Comment: Very true, @IncredibleHat, but this isn't a website about micro-optimising (or code golfing), it's to learn about things. Putting together what you know in a more 'elegant' fashion doesn't meant a thing if you don't know the basic ideas first - which is what the question (and answer) is about.

Answer (score 0):

Your for each needs another variable to add them:

```
foreach ( $get_seller as $keys ) {

     $val_tex = $keys['total']; 
     $sum = += $val_tex
//or...
     $val_tex += $keys['total']; 
//depending on how you want to us val_tex

}
```

The .= adds the value to previous value instead of overwriting it.

Comment: This is simply a mess, and a poor example of a solution.