# Create new elements in a 2d array to hold row totals, column totals, and grand total

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, sum

I have an array

```
$data = array(
    1 => array(1 => 11 ,2 => 21, 3 => 31),
    2 => array(1 => 21 ,2 => 22),
    3 => array(1 => 31 ,2 => 23, 3 => 32),
);
```

which I want to transform to

```
$data = array(
    1 =>       array(1 => 11, 2 => 21, 3 => 31, 'Total' =>  63),
    2 =>       array(1 => 21, 2 => 22,          'Total' =>  43),
    3 =>       array(1 => 31, 2 => 23, 3 => 32, 'Total' =>  83),
    'Total' => array(1 => 63, 2 => 46, 3 => 63, 'Total' => 172),
);
```

The first level and second level keys are dynamic.  In my sample they are 1,2,3, but could be 1 to 10.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to do in a `foreach` loop. What have you tried so far? We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you have with your code, but we're not here to write it all for you (which an answer to this would require us to do). This isn't a free coding service. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I have no idea what " This was questioned by hacking my account" means, but if you really have a legitimate reason for wanting this question gone, please flag your question.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers in Stack Overflow that I could find are related to either sum the elements within an array or the sum of different keys within a multi-dimensional array, but I couldn't find any that addressed both in the same code, so I thought it might be useful to share.

### Premises

Your desired result seems incorrect, by manually doing the calculations the totals should be different than what you described. So I am assuming you just got your example wrong and this is the actual result you want:

```
$data = array(
    1 => array(1 => 11 ,2 => 21, 3 => 31, 'Total' => 63),
    2 => array(1 => 21 ,2 => 22, 'Total' => 43),
    3 => array(1 => 31 ,2 => 23, 3 => 32, 'Total' => 86),
    'Total' => array(1 => 63,2 => 66,3 => 63, 'Total' => 192),
);
```

### Loop and sum arrays

So you basically want two things:

1. For each of the first-level elements of your arrays, you want to calculate the Total. This is done with `array_sum` and you can apply it by doing a `foreach` on the first level of your `$data` array. [More info on array_sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535741/1529324) and [the official php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).
2. Then for each of the second-level elements, you want to sum the ones with the same `key`. To do so, you can use a simple foreach that keeps track of the second-level key and sums each value

### Resulting Code

The resulting code combines these two points with the following logic:

1. Initialize the `Totals` key in the first-level of your `$data` array
2. Loop the first-level elements
3. For each first-level element, use `array_sum` to get the `Total`
4. Loop the second-level elements
5. For each Index of the second level (1, 2, 3), initialize the same index in the `Totals` array
6. For each Index of the second level (1, 2, 3), sum the counter (11, 21, 31) in the Totals array

I've added comments to make it clearer:

```
// Initialize the 'Total' key in the first-level of the array. This will be populated in the foreach
$data['Total'] = [];
// Loop the first level of the array
foreach ($data as $key => $values) {
    // Calculate the sum of the first level of the array, using array_sum
    $data[$key]['Total'] = array_sum($data[$key]);
    // Loop the second level of the array
    foreach ($values as $index => $count) {
        // For each INDEX, create the corresponding element of the Totals array
        if (!isset($data['Total'][$index])) {
            $data['Total'][$index] = 0;
        }
        // Sum this element $count in the Total array
        $data['Total'][$index] += $count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unnecessarily increasing the time complexity by calling an iterative array function along with a nested `foreach()`, perform all summing within the nested loop structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8B7So))

```
$data = [
    1 => [1 => 11, 2 => 21 ,3 => 31],
    2 => [1 => 21, 2 => 22],
    3 => [1 => 31, 2 => 23 ,3 => 32],
];
    
foreach ($data as $k => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $i => $v) {
        $data[$k]['Total'] = ($data[$k]['Total'] ?? 0) + $v;  // accumulate row total
        $data['Total'][$i] = ($data['Total'][$i] ?? 0) + $v;  // accumulate column total
    }
    $data['Total']['Total'] = ($data['Total']['Total'] ?? 0) + $data[$k]['Total']; // accumulate grand total
}
var_export($data);
```